# Parse By nth delimitor in R

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a dataframe like below:

```
Col1    Col2
   A    5!5!!6!!3!!m
   B    7_8!!6!!7!!t

structure(list(Col1 = c("A", "B"), Col2 = c("5!5!!6!!3!!m", "7_8!!6!!7!!t" )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

How do I create a new column that extracts the 3rd parse of the strings found in Col2?

In SQL I am using SPLIT_PART function:

```
SPLIT_PART(Col2, '!!', 3)
```

I am looking to find an equivalent function in R.

Expected output:

```
Col1            Col2    Col3
   A    5!5!!6!!3!!m       3
   B    7_8!!6!!7!!t       7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` option, though the core is funcitonally identical to [Rushabh's data.table based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55798317/8366499).

When given the `simplify=T` argument, `stringr::str_split` will output a matrix, with each match in a column. You can subset the desired column from it to extract the desired position:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
    mutate(Col3 = str_split(Col2, pattern = '!!', simplify=T)[,3])

  Col1         Col2 Col3
1    A 5!5!!6!!3!!m  5!5
2    B 7_8!!6!!7!!t  7_8

df1 %>%
    mutate(Col3 = str_split(Col2, pattern = '!!', simplify=T)[,2])

  Col1         Col2 Col3
1    A 5!5!!6!!3!!m    6
2    B 7_8!!6!!7!!t    6

df1 %>%
  mutate(Col3 = str_split(Col2, pattern = '!!', simplify=T)[,1])

  Col1         Col2 Col3
1    A 5!5!!6!!3!!m  5!5
2    B 7_8!!6!!7!!t  7_8
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract` to extract the digits

```
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(Col3 = as.numeric(str_extract(Col2, "\\d+(?=!![a-z]+$)")))
#  Col1         Col2 Col3
#1    A 5!5!!6!!3!!m    3
#2    B 7_8!!6!!7!!t    7
```

---

If we need it by position, then

```
df1$Col3 <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(df1$Col2, "!!", fixed = TRUE), `[`, 3))
df1$Col3
#[1] 3 7
```

---

Or using `gsubfn` to create a position identifier and then extract the numbers before it

```
library(gsubfn)
p <- proto(fun = function(this, x)  if(count == 3) paste0(";", x))
as.numeric(str_extract(gsubfn("(!!)", p, df1$Col2), "\\d+(?=;)"))
#[1] 3 7
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("A", "B"), Col2 = c("5!5!!6!!3!!m", "7_8!!6!!7!!t"
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks, where do you specify the third parse?

Comment: Only reason I'm asking is because I will have to do multiple parses on different strings by nth delimitor. Trying to find a simple way to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_split` from `stringr` package-

```
> library(stringr)
> library(data.table)
> setDT(dt)[,Col3:=sapply(Col2,function(x) unlist(str_split(x,"!!"))[3])]
```

**Output-**

```
> dt
    Col1      Col2        Col3
1:    A   5!5!!6!!3!!m      3
2:    B   7_8!!6!!7!!t      7
```

**Note**- You can change `position` from `3rd` to `nth` in `function`.